# requesting from?

Tags: sentence

I get confused to understand this sentence

"That's something that U.S. national security advisers may be ***requesting from*** President Donald Trump."

Does it mean that

U.S. national security advisers are requesting Mr.Trump to do something?

Or Trump asking US national security advisers to do something?

Thank you!

Comment: Here's the source: http://www.cnn.com/2017/05/10/cnn10/ten-content-thurs/index.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sentence means that the U.S. national advisers are asking Mr. Trump for *something*. If you include the sentence just before this one, we'll be able to tell you if they are asking Mr. Trump for a *thing* or if they are asking him to *do something*.

Comment: Thanks and actually, the sentence before it is that "Thousands of additional U.S. troops headed to the southern Asian country of Afghanistan." and the next sentence follows

Comment: @Han Can you please edit that into your question?

Comment: First story, are thousands of additional U.S. troops headed to the southern Asian country of Afghanistan. That's something that U.S. national security advisers may be requesting from President Donald Trump.

Comment: @Han Now I understand. The sentence means that U.S. national security advisers may be asking President Trump to send more U.S. troops to Afghanistan. It makes it much easier for us to help you on this site when you include as much context as possible or even the source of the text in your question.

Comment: No worries @Han

Comment: Once again I get downvoted for answering the question :/. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The quotation is from the transcript of a May 11, 2017 program on CNN10 (I'm not sure where that is) as follows:

> I'm Carl Azuz. It's great to see you this Thursday.
>
> First story, are thousands of additional U.S. troops headed to the
>   southern Asian country of Afghanistan. That's something that U.S.
>   national security advisers may be requesting from President Donald
>   Trump.

The transcript apparently has an error: there should be a question mark after "Afghanistan."

So the program is suggesting that the President's national security advisors may request that President Donald Trump approve additional troops for Afghanistan.

Comment: In Britain, I think it would more likely be written "That is something they are requesting ***of*** the Prime Minister". We tend to "request of" rather than "request from". Prepositions again! *From* might be used if emphasis was required as to whom the request was being made. e.g "Make a request for permission!" "Who from?"

Comment: @Han It might be nice just to give Xanne an up-vote for that.